# AWS Cognito signup using Steam social login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, steam, steam-web-api

## Steam social signin with AWS Cognito

I'm creating a cognito user pool which has user phone number as unique key. I want to integrate Steam social signin to record a user's steam ID. Problem is that AWS Cognito supports OpenID connect while Steam only provides **OpenID 2.0** (a deprecated standard).

Has anyone been successful in integrating the two? If no, then what approach should be used?

## Why use steam Signin?

Use case demands that users store their own Steam ID only. Accepting Steam ID directly through a text field could be abused.

## References

1. [OpenID 2.0 vs OpenID connect](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44797/when-do-you-use-openid-vs-openid-connect)
2. [Steam OpenID official documentation](https://steamcommunity.com/dev)
3. [Query string to initiate Steam signin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30869787/7721443)